# VLookup between two workbooks combined with ISNA function. Run-time Error '1004': Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am working on ws1 which is a worksheet in "New" workbook. it contains Bill No in column 1 and other relevant information in other columns.
I want to Vlookup in another workbook called "PDA" and in that worksheet with sheet name "Sheet1" which has Bill no in Column F and the data that I want to copy in column G. If the Bill No is not present in PDA>Sheet1, then I want to return the value 0, because I have to sum the amount later.
I have written this code, but it is giving error. Kindly help me with the issue.
I am getting error in this line

> .Cells(i, 4) = "=If(ISNA(VLookup(.Cells(i, 1).Value2, y, 2,
>   False)),0,VLookup(.Cells(i, 1).Value2, y, 2, False))"

```
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mrisingh\Desktop\6-Eccs Billing List.xlsx")
Set x = wb1.Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range("B2:E100000")
Set ws1 = Workbooks("New").Worksheets("Reconciliation")
With ws1
For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Cells(i, 3) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 1).Value2, x, 4, False)
Next i
End With
Set b = wb1.Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range("B2:K100000")
With ws1
For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Cells(i, 9) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 1).Value2, b, 10, False)
Next i
End With
wb1.Close savechanges:=False

Dim y As Range
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mrisingh\Desktop\PDA.xlsx")
Set y = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F845:G10000")
With ws1
For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Cells(i, 4) = "=If(ISNA(VLookup(.Cells(i, 1).Value2, y, 2, False)),0,VLookup(.Cells(i, 1).Value2, y, 2, False))"
Next i
End With
wb2.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: You can't have everything as one string as you are trying to combine formula and vba variable. The question is, what do you want to have in your output? Is it formula in `cell(I,4)` or just the result of the formula?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing VBA pieces into an Excel formula - that will not work. Excel does not know what `.Cells(i, 1).Value2` or `y` means, but that is what you write into the cell. VBA, on the other hand, doesn't replace `.Cells(i, 1).Value2` or `y` with the range itself as is it inside a constant string (within quotes), and VBA leaves those strings alone.

So a first attempt would be to write (untested as I don't have your data, but you hopefully get the idea)

```
dim lookupAdr as string, f as string
lookupAdr = "[" & wb2.name & "]" & "Sheet1!" & y.address
f = "=If(ISNA(VLookup(" & .Cells(i, 1).address & ", " _
    & lookupAdr & ", 2, False)),0,VLookup( " _
    & .Cells(i, 1).address & ", " & lookupAdr & ", 2, False))"
Debug.Print lookupAdr
Debug.Print f
.Cells(i, 4).formula = f
```

Note that I write the formula and the address of the lookup first into string variables - this helps to find errors. Note also that you should write formulas always to the property `.formula` of a cell, not to the `.value` property.

However, there is room for improvement:
Unless you are still on Excel 2003, you can use the `IFERROR` formula so that you don't have to repeat the `VLOOKUP`-part. This would lead to a much easier formula (again untested):

```
 f = "=IFERROR(VLookup( " & .Cells(i, 1).address & ", " & lookupAdr & ", 2, False), 0)"
```

As a general rule when you try to create a formula within VBA, it is often helpfull to go the different way first: Write the final formula that you want to have into one cell, go to the VBA-Editor, open the *Immediate Window* (press **[Ctrl]+[G]**) and enter `? activecell.formula`. Then, write your code and compare the formula you create within VBA with the one you saw in the immediate window.

And, as advice: Use *meaningfull* variable names. `y` is not really a good name for a range variable - use something like `lookupRange`. Everyone that will read the code (and that includes you!) will be thankfull.